# Access VM localhost from Host

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox, vmware, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have installed Redhat 7 on the VMware which is on windows 10.

Now, I am trying to access RHEL `localhost(10.10.1.***)` from the `Host(Windows)`. I am able to access `10.10.1.***` from windows through putty **but does not work when tested on browser.**

On RHEL `10.10.1.***:8080` displays the apache default page but it does not work when tested `10.10.1.***:8080`. RHEL VMware network settings is already bridged.

I have also changed the settings of `c:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
#127.0.0.1 localhost
#::1 localhost

10.10.1.### localhost
::1 localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check firewall and SELinux status? You can do it by running the following commands:

Check SELinux status:

```
sestatus
```

Add or uncomment this line in your config file:

```
setenforce Permissive
```

To check Firewall status use:

```
systemctl status firewalld
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
```

Reference: [How to Disable SELinux Temporarily or Permanently](https://www.tecmint.com/disable-selinux-in-centos-rhel-fedora/)